# different print results from exactly the same code

Tags: c#, .net, printing, gdi+

I have two programs, one is a windows service and the other a windows forms application. They have exactly the same code for printing one A4 page. They both print to the same network printer and they start drawing at position 0,0.

```
private void pd_PrintCustomsDocument(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
  Graphics g = ev.Graphics;

  g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
  using (Font courierBig = new Font("Courier", 15))
  {
    g.DrawString("Shipping Invoice", courierBig, Brushes.Black, new Point(0, 0));
    // etc
  }
}
```

The windows forms app prints the document correctly, a page margin is used. But the service starts printing exactly at the edge of the paper.
Is there a difference between printing with gdi+ from a service and a windows forms application?

The code for the actual printing is divided into a base and subclass for overriding default printer settings like selecting page from a different tray:

```
public class PrintBehaviour : IDisposable
{
    private string mPrinterName;
    private PrintPageEventHandler mHandler;
    private PrintDocument mDocument = new PrintDocument();

    public PrintBehaviour(string name, PrintPageEventHandler handler)
    {
        mPrinterName = name;
        mHandler = handler;
        mDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
    }

    public virtual void SettingsOverride(PrintDocument doc) {}

    public void Print()
    {
        SettingsOverride(mDocument);
        mDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = mPrinterName;
        mDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(mHandler);
        mDocument.Print();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        mDocument.Dispose();
    }
}

public sealed class CustomsPrintBehaviour : PrintBehaviour
{
    private string mPaperTray;

    public CustomsPrintBehaviour(string name, PrintPageEventHandler handler, string paperTray)
        : base(name, handler)
    {
        mPaperTray = paperTray;
    }

    public override void SettingsOverride(PrintDocument doc)
    {
        base.SettingsOverride(doc);
        doc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

        foreach (PaperSource source in doc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources)
        {
            if (source.SourceName.Trim().ToUpper() == mPaperTray)
            {
                doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = source;

                PaperSize size = new PaperSize { RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4 };

                doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = size;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and called like this:

```
using (var pb = new CustomsPrintBehaviour(_customsPrinter, pd_PrintCustomsDocument, kv["PaperTray"].ToUpper()))
{
  pb.Print();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual printing code?

Comment: edited the OP with the printer classes

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> GDI+ functions and classes are **not supported** for use within a
>   Windows service. Attempting to use these functions and classes from a
>   Windows service may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished
>   service performance and run-time exceptions or errors.

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with pagemargins